# Sox split .mp3 wav by silence

Tags: audio, split, mp3, sox, wav

mp3 file with around 200 sentences. They are separated by silence of around 500-1000, but it is not fixed or equal.

What is the best way to split to one file per sentence? Preferably with [sox](/questions/tagged/sox). I heard it should work but couldn't found any clear documentation.

I saw [Split audio file but only in pauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707843/split-audio-file-but-only-in-pauses)
but couldn't understand what is

```
1 0.5 2% - above_periods, duration, threshold.

1 2.0 2% - below_periods, duration, threshold.
```

Comment: You might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014064/how-to-batch-split-audio-files-wherever-there-is-silence

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I so this but I don't understand the parameters, can you explain what is 1 3.0 0.1% 1 0.3 0.1% : newfile : restart?

Comment: Please read all the answers in the linked question. One of them lists the explanations for the parameters.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I read it but I don't understand what they mean by above_period and below_period

Comment: have you read [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox)? Look for `above-periods`.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I want to split 1 wav file to multiple wav files, segmented by silence , I don't understand how this helps me

Comment: If you don't understand how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014064/how-to-batch-split-audio-files-wherever-there-is-silence) answers your question ... I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320517/377345) should contain all necessary explanations on the parameters.